# Получение данных через сокет

Tags: c#, сокет

Решил наконец добраться до сокетов c# и поставил себе задачу: полчение данных с сайта, который передает их с использованием сокета wss://socket.xx.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket

```
Request Headers
____________________________________________________ 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Host: socket.xx.io
Origin: https://xx.io
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: E5DOHHXz4ppfBv2zeDynyQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
```

Каким образом это лучше сделать? Пытался помучить ClientWebSocket ,но чувствую, что это в корне неверно.

```
ClientWebSocket WS = new ClientWebSocket();
await WS.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://socket.xx.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"), CancellationToken.None);

ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345"));
await WS.SendAsync(arraySegment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
WebSocketReceiveResult result = await WS.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, CancellationToken.None);
var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count);
```

Comment: `это в корне неверно` - почему?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ никогда не работал с Socket.io (https://habr.com/ru/post/498996/)

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что в c# у вас выбора-то особо и нет, либо используете `ClientWebSocket`, либо пишете свою реализацию. Вы можете эту самую реализацию взять, например у других, установив себе стороннюю библиотек, которая будет работать так, как вам надо (первое [попавшееся](https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp)). Сам `ClientWebSocket` вы реализовали так, как надо, ошибка лишь в том, что вы не используете `using` или не закрываете сами все это дело.